# How to give an ID to this <?php $row->name;?> so I can access the property in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am newbie in Code Igniter... I have an edit button in front of every row. Now, what I want is that after I click on the edit button, a pop up/model box/lightbox should appear without the page refreshing, and all the fields should appear in that box.

```
       <?php foreach($records as $row){?>
<tr>
<td class = "click"><?php echo $row->name; ?>  </td>



    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.click').editable('<?php echo site_url('categoryController/editCategory');?>',
       {

     });

        });
```

Comment: your question is not clear for me?

Comment: look i have a table which contain many rows .. and each row there is an edit button .. so now i want to edit the row or form without a page refresh ..                 <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="edit" "<?php $row->name_id;?>">Edit</a>       this is code i am passing an id so that id will go to the controller where i have written a query which ill delete the whole row where id is etc etc so now what i want to do is to access this line through ajax so i can send the request to controller or send an id to controller ..now do u get it ?

Comment: try [this](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Comment: waooooooo this is awsome dear ...this is something even better

Comment: i updated my question .. as u said i am now using a editable plugin ..I’m having a bit of trouble understanding how to send data to the Controller. i want to send the name .. how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include the `id` and `name` of the element, like:

```
<tr>
<td class = "click" id="field" name="field_name"><?php echo $row->name; ?>  </td>
</tr>
```

then in your js:

```
$("#field").editable("<?php echo site_url('categoryController/editCategory'); ?>",
 { 
        indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>", // or any image
        onblur    : 'cancel',
        tooltip   : 'Click to edit...',
        cancel    : 'Cancel',
        submit    : 'OK'
});
```

then in your controller you retrieve the value with:

```
$this->input->post('field_name');
```

for more info see the [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) website.

Comment: the image is optional, you can set text indicator if you like or not setting anything at all :)

Comment: there are two problems i am facing now .. one when i check on firebug the value is going '0' and next only one row now is editable .. as i have code my table in a for each loop ... like this  '  <?

        <?php foreach($records as $row){?>
        <tr>
         
         <td  id = "field"  name = "cat_name">
         <?php echo $row->cat_name; ?>  </td>
         <td> '

Comment: @user1972143 - for the next problem change the $('#feild').editable to $('.click').editable this will solve it and keep the name attribute the same for all elements. as for the first problem the value that's passed is the value of the field. try the solution now and let me know what are the results.

Comment: all your editable elements should share the same class. and the same name if you are dealing with the same post fetching in your controller

Comment: obviously when the td is in loop they all autometically getting a same id and class

Comment: @user1972143 - great then let them have the same name attribute, and change $('#feild').editable  to $('.click').editable

Comment: @ mamdouh alramadan   .. thanks very much .. one problem solved ..now check my model and controller i posted above

Comment: @user1972143 - please do not post the updates in the answers section just edit your question and add whatever you want

Comment: and answering your question " which is not relative to your main problem " in your model do $this->db->update($cat_name); will be enough cuz you are passing array here not string variable.

Comment: welcome :). please mark as solved if there are no further questions :)